# How do I run the Ubuntu Phone Nexus7 image in a VM?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, virtualization, phone

Do I need to go through the device imaging steps with an ADT VM, a specific qemu configuration, something else, not possible?

How do I run the Ubuntu Phone Nexus7 image in a VM?  Any of the above options would be okay.  I'm just looking for a definitive answer.